# How to parse a JSON string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I imagine this is really basic and I'm missing something obvious.

I want to access the values in a variable called graph_data which is holding the following JSON object:

```
graph_data= {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0,0,8.2,7,5.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

When I try to get graph_data.data.length I get an error that graph_data.data is "undefined".

I can't seem to get graph_data.data[0] to return anything either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works for me... Can you show actual code that doesn't work & causes an error?

Comment: is this the format of the data or is it what you're expecing your're getting back from something? as is, it should work fine

Comment: It should work fine. Try declaring the variable with the 'var' statement - maybe you define & access the variable in different scope.

Comment: this is working http://jsfiddle.net/2bu2Z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine:

```
graph_data = {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0,0,8.2,7,5.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]};
console.log(graph_data.data.length); // Outputs 25
```

Are you sure you have an object literal and not a string?

If you have the latter you need to parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
graph_data = JSON.parse('{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0,0,8.2,7,5.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}');
```

You'll need a parser for older browsers without native JSON support like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: A-ha! That was it. I needed to JSON.parse it into an object. It had become a string, I guess, because I've just switched to CakePHP 2.0 and switched to the new XML method Xml::toArray, which renders XML to a string and not to a JSON object. JSON.parse was it -- it's all working and plotting my jquery charts. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

```
graph_data= {"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.4,0,0,8.2,7,5.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]};

for (var i = 0; i < graph_data.data.length; i++){
    $("body").append(graph_data.data[i]+"<br/>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtDaH/

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Homer. Much appreciated!